# Replace the last character of string that matches the pattern

Tags: bash, shell

```
arr=(
  "./***framework-client-1.2.3-98765-demo.zip"
  "./***-example-service-3.2.1-98765-demo.zip"
  "./***-docs-client-4.3.2-98765-demo.zip"
)

for package in ${arr[@]}
do
  package=${package:2:4} # remove ".zip"
  package=${package//"***"/"react"} # change every "***" to "react"

  if [[ $package == *"@reactframework"* ]]; then # matches "reactframework"
      package=$(echo $package | sed 's/-/\/''/1') #changes the first dash
  else # matches react-framework
      package=$(echo $package | sed 's/-/\/''/2') # changes the second dash
  
   # trying to change the last char before the first digit to "@"
   # reactframework-client-1.2.3-98765-demo -> reactframework-client@1.2.3-98765-demo
   # react-example-service-3.2.1-98765-demo -> react-example/service@3.2.1-98765-demo
   # react-docs-client-4.3.2-98765-demo -> react-docs/client@4.3.2-98765-demo.zip
   fi
```

done

I'm trying to change the last char (i.e.- "-") before the occurrence of any digit to "@".
I was looking through sed command but was not really sure what would be the good way to apply the change.

Answer (score 0):

Match the first occurrence of dash then a digit, capturing the digit, and put it back. Use the *extended* option `-E` for simpler syntax.

```
sed -E 's/-([0-9])/@\1/'
```

---

```
echo "reactframework-client-1.2.3-98765-demo" | sed -E 's/-([0-9])/@\1/'
```

Output:

```
reactframework-client@1.2.3-98765-demo
```